# Mock an AngularJS module to pass to another

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm having some trouble mocking a factory belonging to one of my modules. The factory I would like to mock has 2 dependencies:

**Factory class:**

```
angular.module('serviceapp')
.factory('claims.service', ['applicationSettings', 'localStorageService', function (applicationSettings, localStorageService) {
    //Factory code here
}]);
```

**Test class:**

```
//Instantiate some values
var mockAppSettings = {};
var mockStorageService = {};
var $factory; //Will hold my factory

//Targeting my module for mocking
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('serviceapp'));

//Providing some values for the dependencies of my module
beforeEach(module('serviceapp', function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('applicationSettings', mockAppSettings);
    $provide.value('localStorageService', mockStorageService);
}));

//Problems start here
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    $factory = $injector.get('claims.service');
}));
```

I get an error message

`Failed to instantiate module serviceapp due to:
 Failed to instantiate module accountModule due to:
 Module 'accountModule' is not available!`

When investigating I see that `accountModule` is listed as a dependency for the `serviceApp` module.

**App.module class:**

```
angular.module('serviceapp', [accountModule])
```

However I'm having some trouble mocking this module to pass to serviceapp. I have tried to mock the accountModule in the same way I have mocked the serviceapp in the beginning however this is still bring up the same error message. How can I mock and pass one module to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.mock.module('serviceapp')` shouldn't be read literally. It doesn't mock a module. It is the same thing as `module('serviceapp')` and is used in modular environments where `module` is reserved.

So, all that

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('serviceapp'));
beforeEach(module('serviceapp', ...));
```

does is loading `serviceapp` twice (doesn't hurt but doesn't help either).

To avoid `Module 'accountModule' is not available!`, it should be (re)defined:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  angular.module('accountModule', [])
});
```

The problem with this approach is that even if it was defined, it will be overridden to the end of test run. If real `accountModule` needs to be used in other tests, this won't be possible.

The appropriate solution for similar design issues (this also applies to dependencies that aren't desirable in tests, e.g. router modules) is

```
angular.module('serviceapp', ['accountModule']);

angular.module('serviceapp.internal', [])
.factory('claims.service',...);
```

Here `serviceapp` serves as a shallow wrapper for `serviceapp.internal`, while the latter can be safely tested. If `serviceapp` is top-level module that is used for bootstrapping, this indicates that the application wasn't modularized enough, this hurts testing.

Comment: Ahhh I see! Thank you so much for providing some (really great) insight into this! I'll give this a go

Comment: Also, notice that $provide.value is redundant. The same thing can be done with object argument https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module#usage .